# Get class properties in string list in c#?

Tags: c#, reflection

Please find the below entities :

```
public class Country
{
    public int Id;
    public string name;
    public string code;
}
public class City
{
    public int Id;
    public string name;
    public country {get;set;}
}
public class Person
{
    public int Id;
    public string name;
    public DateTime dob;
    public string gender;
    public city {get;set;}
}
```

I need to get all properties as string list as mentioned below:

```
"Id"
"name"
"dob"
"gender"
"city.Id"
"city.name"
"city.country.Id"
"city.country.name"
"city.country.code"
```

And my method to get property is

```
private List<string> GetProps(Type type)
{
    var result=new List<string>();
    var properties = type.GetProperties().ToDictionary(x => x, x => x.GetType().GetProperties());
    foreach (var item in properties)
    {
        result.Add(item.Key.ToString());
    }
    return result;
}

GetProps(typeof(Person)); // calling in main method;
```

The coming result is

```
"Id"
"name"
"dob"
"gender"
"city"
```

But my expected result is :
"Id"
"name"
"dob"
"gender"
"city.Id"
"city.name"
"city.country.Id"
"city.country.name"
"city.country.code"

Please help :)

Comment: you need to recursivly iterate the properties. So when a property itself is some complex object, iterate it's porperties also via recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching I got this:

```
public class GetAllPropertiesHelper
{

    private static Dictionary<string, object> result = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    private static bool IsSimpleType(Type type)
    {
        return
            type.IsValueType ||
            type.IsPrimitive ||
            new Type[]
            {
                        typeof(String),
                        typeof(Decimal),
                        typeof(DateTime),
                        typeof(DateTimeOffset),
                        typeof(TimeSpan),
                        typeof(Guid)

            }.Contains(type) ||
                    Convert.GetTypeCode(type) != TypeCode.Object;
    }
    public static Dictionary<string, object> GetProperties(object obj)
    {
        string ObjName = obj.GetType().Name;

        var PropertyList = GetProperties(obj, ObjName);
        return PropertyList;
    }

    private static Dictionary<string, object> GetProperties(object obj, string objName)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return result;

        string ObjTypeName = objName;


        Type objType = obj.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] properties = objType.GetProperties();

        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            object propValue = property.GetValue(obj, null);


            if (IsSimpleType(property.PropertyType))
            {
                if (!CheckDuplicateKeyInDictionary(ObjTypeName + "." + property.Name))
                {
                    result.Add(ObjTypeName + "." + property.Name, value: propValue);

                }

            }
            else if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType)) // if object type is of Enumeration type.

            {
                try
                {
                    if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string[]))
                    {
                        if (!CheckDuplicateKeyInDictionary(ObjTypeName + "." + property.Name))
                        {
                            result.Add(ObjTypeName + "." + property.Name, value: Convert.ToString(propValue));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        IEnumerable enumerable = (IEnumerable)propValue;

                        if (enumerable != null)
                        {
                            object enumTypeValue = enumerable.GetEnumerator().GetType();

                            if (!CheckDuplicateKeyInDictionary(ObjTypeName + "." + property.Name))
                            {
                                result.Add(ObjTypeName + "." + property.Name, value: enumTypeValue);

                            }

                            foreach (object child in enumerable)
                            {
                                ObjTypeName = ObjTypeName + "." + property.Name + "." + child.GetType().Name;

                                GetProperties(child, ObjTypeName);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (!CheckDuplicateKeyInDictionary(ObjTypeName + "." + property.Name))
                            {
                                result.Add(ObjTypeName + "." + property.Name, value: null);
                            }

                            //TODO Get the type of the enum and iterate over to collect class propertes.
                        }


                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                if (propValue == null) // if object type is not intialized.
                {
                    GetProperties(property.PropertyType, ObjTypeName + "." + property.Name);
                }
                else
                {
                    ObjTypeName = ObjTypeName + "." + propValue.GetType().Name;

                    Object objTypeValue = (Object)propValue;

                    object ObjValue = objTypeValue.GetType();

                    if (ObjValue != null)
                    {
                        if (!CheckDuplicateKeyInDictionary(ObjTypeName + "." + property.Name))
                        {
                            result.Add(ObjTypeName + "." + property.Name, value: ObjValue);

                        }

                        GetProperties(propValue, ObjTypeName + "." + property.Name);
                    }

                }

            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static Dictionary<string, object> GetProperties(Type objType, string objName)
    {
        string ObjTypeName = objName;
        PropertyInfo[] properties = objType.GetProperties();

        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            object propValue = null;



            if (IsSimpleType(property.PropertyType))
            {
                result.Add(ObjTypeName + "." + property.Name, value: propValue);
            }
            else if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                GetProperties(property.PropertyType, ObjTypeName + "." + property.Name);

            }
        }

        return result;

    }

    private static bool CheckDuplicateKeyInDictionary(string keyName)
    {
        if (result.ContainsKey(keyName))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

}
```

Then just call the method as mentioned below:

```
 var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Person));
 var res = GetAllPropertiesHelper.GetProperties(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to recursivly iterate the properties. So when a property itself is some complex object, iterate it's porperties also via recursion:

```
private List<string> GetProps(Type type)
{
    var result=new List<string>();
    var properties = type.GetProperties());
    foreach (var item in properties)
    {
        var propType = item.PropertyType;
        if(propType == typeof(int) || propType == typeof(int) || ...)
            result.Add(item.Name);
        else
            result.AddRange(GetProps(propType));
    }
    return result;
}

GetProps(typeof(Person)); // calling in main method;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Is it any shortcut to identity prop is class type or not instead of ```if(propType == typeof(int) || propType == typeof(string) || ...)```

Comment: @PrasannaKumarJ I don't know any. Anyway you need to concat the type-names with a dot in some way.